# How to press windows key using pywinauto python

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

Hello I want to write a program to automate windows 10 but to do so I need to open startmenu by pressing windows key using pywinauto plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```python
from pywinauto import Application

Application().start(r'mmc printmanagement.msc') # Warning! it spawns child process

# connect to that child process
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path='mmc.exe')

# print main window with the title
print(app.windows())

app.PrintManagement.dump_tree() # print identifiers for further automation
```

Comment: It is returning MMC Cannot open the file printmanagement.msc Error

Comment: Can you copy the file there  %systemroot%\system32\printmanagement.msc

Comment: why open printmanagement.msc, when the question is how to invoke the windows key?